# Docker compose doesn't get picked up by reverse proxy

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy, docker, docker-compose

I have a docker-compose that creates a container with a http server that doesn't get picked up by jwilder's nginx reverse proxy but it works wen instantiated by hand.

```
version: '2'
services:
    mongo:
        image: tutum/mongodb
        expose:
            - "27017"
        environment:
            - AUTH=no

    backend:
        build:
            context: "./instance"
        hostname: instance
        ports:
            - "1080:8080"
        expose:
            - "8080"
        links:
            - mongo

    frontend:
        build:
            context: "./instancegui"
        ports:
            - "80"
        environment:
            - VIRTUAL_HOST=some.host.com
            - LETSENCRYPT_HOST=some.host.com
            - LETSENCRYPT_EMAIL=someone@somewhere.com
```

the config file generated by the reverse proxy says upstream{...DOWN}
but the container runs fine when instantiated like so

```
docker run --name group_frontend_1 -p 80 -e "VIRTUAL_HOST=some.host.com" -e "LETSENCRYPT_HOST=some.host.com" -e "LETSENCRYPT_EMAIL=someone@somewhere.com" -d db70e6003db9
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok found the solution

the problem is that the contained is not in a network watched by the proxy container, the most direct way is to set the contained in bridge mode

```
network_mode: "bridge"
```

and ports 80 is overkill its only needed expose

```
expose:
        - "80"
```

sources:
https://github.com/jwilder/nginx-proxy/issues/552
https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/3012

Answer (score 0):

Why not use a plain and simple nginx image like [this](https://github.com/driverpt/pixelscamp-bootstrap-microservices/tree/master/stage2/nginx). Docker already does DNS for you.

Comment: the DockerFile inside ./instancegui is similar to yours, its the official nginx image with my project files.

Comment: Could you elaborate on the "Docker already does DNS for you."

Comment: You have a container named "frontend". If you `ping frontend` inside the container, it will resolve to the container's IP.
What jwilder/nginx-proxy does is execute a Go program that calls the Docker API and build a `/etc/hosts` file.
Thats why i say, Docker already does DNS resolution for you.